# How do i find the Physical Socket ID / number a process is running on?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I would like to know if there is any way to find the actual physical processor / socket number a current process is running on or the mapping for the same provided a logical processor number.

I have a 8 socket system resulting in a total of 128 (0-127) logical processors. 
As from what i have read in msdn, they would be divided into 2 processor groups of 64 logical processors each. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405503

I have tried looking at cpuid and GetNumaProcessorNodeEx
from cpuid, APIC id helps identify the logical processors ID, and from GetNumaProcessorNodeEx, i get the numa node (this i found to be useful IF there are 64 or less number of logical processors)
Is it also possible if a logical processor is hyper thread?

I am trying to create a tool like this.

processor no  - socket/core id/HT

processor 0 - 0/0/0

processor 1 - 0/1/1

processor 2 - 0/2/0

...

processor 8 - 1/0/0

processor 9 - 1/1/1

...

Any help or links to figure this out would be great.

Thank you

Comment: This website is **not** a link harvester.

Comment: @Neal I am not just trying to harvest links. I am only looking for help even in the way of re-directing me to look at other options. I am in no way expecting someone to answer me. Even guiding me towards a solution would be very helpful.

Comment: May i please know the reasons for the down votes? i could rephrase / improve the question.

Comment: This site is not going to provide you with links. It is not constructive at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket/core/thread hierarchy is in the bits of the APIC ID.
The N low bits are the thread, M low are the core, the remaining high bits are the socket.
To find N and M, you need to use some CPUID codes:
Code 1 gives you the number of threads per socket (somewhere in EBX).
Code 4 gives you the number of cores per socket (in EAX).
If, for example, you have 12 threads and 6 cores per socket, then the lowest bit is the thread ID, the next 3 are the core, the rest are the socket.

Comment: In case anyone else needs some documentation help with it, i can provide a link here. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-64-architecture-processor-topology-enumeration/